# MySQL datetime warning #1264

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Why does the date

```
2010-10-11 24:00:00
```

give me a MySQL warning? The data is then not written to the database.

```
Warning: #1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'date' at row 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`24` hour is not exists, last hour is a `23`.

Hours can be of range `0 - 23`
Minutes `0 - 59`
Seconds `0 - 59`